# Updating hystrix configuration in camel route

Tags: apache-camel, hystrix

Is there a way to update hystrix configuration at runtime? I am using Java DSL to create route and referring to a hystrix configuration bean in SimpleRegistry (also tried with SpringBean registry). Nothing seems to change when I modify this bean and then do `camelContext.addRouteDefinition()`.